# How to add arithmetic operator in SQL reader in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I had select a data from a SQL Server table. May I know how to add arithmetic operator in C#?

For example, if select the `TransID` from table is 14491, so if write in the arithmetic addition operator condition. Then the `transID` number will increase by 1. The expected result is 14492

```
protected void TransID()
{
    string UniIDSQL = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(INV_TRANS_ID AS INT)),0) AS TRANSID FROM  CIMProRPT01.dbo.OTH_INV_TRANSACTION";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(UniIDSQL, con))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    MMSNewID.Text = reader["TRANSID"].ToString();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Error getting Unique ID ";
                lblResults.Text += err.Message;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string UniIDSQL = "SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CAST(INV_TRANS_ID AS INT)),0) + 1 AS TRANSID FROM  CIMProRPT01.dbo.OTH_INV_TRANSACTION";
```

Please note that TransID will return the same (non-unique) value when executed simultaneously in two threads (for example in two concurrent asp.net requests). You should use either table with identity column, uniqueidentifiers instead of int or sql server sequences to get unique values.